# EC2 port 80 refused to connect on public IP but can connect using private IP

Tags: iptables, security-groups, aws-ec2, connection-refused

### Question simplified

I can do `curl {publicip}:4321` but not `curl {publicip}:80` or `curl {publicip}`. But from the server's ssh, i can run `curl {privateip}:80` and `curl localhost:80` without any issues. And also, both port 80 and port 4321 are added to [inbound rules in security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEMP.png). Why is that happening?

### The Story

I'm new to AWS EC2. I recently created an EC2 t4g nano instance, and ran a NodeJS server using PM2. The server listens on port 4321. Then using iptables, I redirected port 80 to port 4321. Then in security groups, I added inbound rule from "Anywhere IP" to port 80 (HTTP).

Everything was working, I was able to connect using the instance's public IP to the server until today morning, when I suddenly wasn't able to even SSH to the server. The instance status in AWS console showed as 'running', but in status check, 1/2 was not successfull. It showed "Instance reachability failed". Then, I tried to restart the instance, it worked and then I could SSH it.

Now, I restarted PM2, and then again added the redirecting rule to iptables. But now, I cant connect to port 80 using public IP.

I can run `curl localhost:80` and `curl {privateip}:80`, it connects without any issues. When I run `curl {publicip}:80` or `curl {publicip}` it shows 'Connection refused`. As I said, port 80 already exists in the [security group's inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEMP.png).

I added port 4321 to the inbound rules of the security group, and I can connect without any issues using `curl {publicip}:4321` but not `curl ${publicip}:80`. How's that possible? Did I miss something?